# C++ getline(), the second run of this function doesn't work

Tags: c++, input, getline

I can't figure out what's my simple IO problem:

this is the code where I do the IO:

```
cout << "Enter an Employee name: ";
getline(cin, empName);
cout << "Employee Position: "  ;
cin >> empPos;
cout << "Enter the Number of Years of Experience: ";
cin >> numOfExp;
cout << "Enter the deprtment Number: ";
cin >> deptNum;
```

and here is my wrong output:
the first time that the name is read everything is fine but the second time it looks like something is automatically is passed into the name without asking the user to input anything fot the name.

Here is my output:

```
Name:               Unknown
Department Number:          0
Employee Position:          E
Years of Experience:        0
Salary:                     0
Total Number of Employees:  1
Enter an Employee name: arasd d
Employee Position: s
Enter the Number of Years of Experience: 12
Enter the deprtment Number: 12
Name:                       arasd d
Department Number:          12
Employee Position:          s
Years of Experience:        12
Salary:                     0
Total Number of Employees:  1
Enter an Employee name: Employee Position:
```

As you see the last line is the problem;
any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `getline` behaves differently about when it stops reading.

Comment: Don't mix `getline` and `>>`. Also, you completely forgot to check the return value of any of the input operations. This is basically a disaster.

Comment: I don't to do any error checking at this point, I just want to simply make sure the program runs assuming that the user enters a correct input.

Comment: As for mixing the getline and >>, I don't know how to read input a string that has a space in between and store it to a single string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the last thing you read before the `std::getline()` is an integer (or something else using `operator>>()`. The formatted input operators stop reading when the first character not matching their format is encountered. For example, for an integer reading stops the monent a non-digit is entered (except for a leading sign). Thus, after reading an integer the newline character used to indicate that the input is done is still in the input buffer.

To deal with the stuck newline you can just skip any leading whitespace before calking `std::getline()`:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, name)) {
    ...
}
```

BTW, there is **never** a situation where you don't want to check user-input! User-input **always** needs checking, even in the most trivial programs where the input is *assumed* to be right! It help with locating the actual problems dramatically. Given your output it looks as if tve input actually didn't match what is being read...

Comment: thanks, but I fixed the problem by entering `cin.ignore()` at the end, so it clears the buffer every time it's done reading inputs.

Comment: Note, that using `std::cin.ignore()` is an insufficient fix! Try inputting a space in front of the newline: `123 \n` and you're back to where you were. If you may have leading whitespace or an empty name, you might want to use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`: this skips as many characters as needed to get to the next newline. Persinally, I think using `std::ws` when switching between formatted and unformatted I/O is much simpler and more idiomatic.

Comment: I guess I am not sure where you want me to insert that piece of code, but i tested it with a leading space without doing any modification and still works.

Comment: The point is, `std::cin.ignore()` just ignores one character. If you enter a number followed by a space and only then enter, the stream is right on the newline character when the `std::getline()` is seen. In that case you need to ignore more than one character. More precisely, you need to ignore all character up to and including the newline. This is what the call to `std::cin.ignore()` in my previous comment does.